# My flex items wont take a width and height property and stay on one line

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

I haven't used flexbox for a while but I'm not exactly sure why my width and height aren't taking effect for each of the flex items and they all seem to be taking an equal width but not the width I have input. They also all sit on one line but I haven't included A no wrap.

```
    const Filter = () => {
    return (      
      <div className="store-results-inner-container">
        {alphabetIntoArray.map((c, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i} className="alphabet-individual-container">
              {filteredValues
                .filter(store => store.title.rendered.startsWith(c)).length === 0 
                ? <h1 ref={ el => itemsRef.current[i] = el } className={'Grey'}>{c}</h1>
                : <h1 ref={ el => itemsRef.current[i] = el } className={'notGrey'}>{c}</h1>   
              }         
              {filteredValues
                .filter(store => store.title.rendered.startsWith(c))
                .map((item, index) => (   
                  <li key={index}>{item.title.rendered}</li>
                ))}
              </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

css:

```
    .store-results-inner-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
    height: auto;
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    background-color: seagreen;
}

.alphabet-individual-container {
    width: 1150px;
    height: 200px;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}
```

output:  [image]

desired output:

I want them to have an equal height and width and have 3 per column which are responsive.

Comment: You could convert to css grid and use templates with mixmax. Or, going the route you are going, set the character parent container to row wrap as well as setting the characters max-width at 33% and width at 100%. A lengthy work around but that's my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't put a flex-wrap, the default is no-wrap, you need to put `flex-wrap:wrap`, because all items are trying to fit at the same line.
And if you want them to have equal height and width you need to specify it as well, you are giving different width and height to them. You can try to put width of 30% and a fixed height.

I think a better solution is to use a grid.

I did a quick example, maybe it can help:
https://codepen.io/JonathanDamiani/pen/abBOgBR